# How to check for special characters when validating a form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add form validation into my form. I've managed to do it for character length, numbers, letters and all of them work fine, but it doesn't seem to work for special characters, such as @ & * etc.

I've tried following an example from a previous question which created a variable for all the different special characters, and then I did here what I did with my other checks, matched the field input to the variable with the special characters to see if there are any, but it is not detecting them.

This is my JavaScript for this:

```
function ValidateActInsert() {
var specialChars = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/;
        if (document.actorInsert.actInsert.value.match(specialChars)) {
        alert ("Only characters A-Z, a-z and 0-9 are allowed!")
        document.actorInsert.actInsert.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return (true);
}
```

And this is the HTML form that I am trying to do this on:

```html
<form name = "actorInsert" align = "center" action="actorInserting.php" onSubmit="return ValidateActInsert()">
    Actor name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "actInsert"
    <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Insert">
</form>
```

The code itself makes sense to me and i'd imagine that it would work and I honestly have no idea as to why it isn't

Comment: Instead of trying to catch every possible special symbol, try catching only alphanumeric symbols. Much easier

Comment: @SterlingArcher gave him an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were catching every symbol.

Let's just simple only allow
`a-z` lowercase, 
`A-Z` uppercase and or
`0-9` as @SterlingArcher said.

`/[^a-zA-Z ]/g` Will allow only a-z and A-Z

`/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g` Will allow only a-z, A-Z, and 0-9

> Letters and Numbers:

```js
function ValidateActInsert() {
    var specialChars = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g;
    if (document.actorInsert.actInsert.value.match(specialChars)) {
        alert ("Only characters A-Z, a-z and 0-9 are allowed!")
        document.actorInsert.actInsert.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return (true);
}
```

```html
<form name = "actorInsert" align = "center" action="actorInserting.php" onSubmit="return ValidateActInsert()">
    Actor name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "actInsert"
    <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Insert">
</form>
```

> Numbers only

```js
function ValidateActInsert() {
    var specialChars = /[^a-zA-Z ]/g;
    if (document.actorInsert.actInsert.value.match(specialChars)) {
        alert ("Only characters A-Z, a-z are allowed!")
        document.actorInsert.actInsert.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return (true);
}
```

```html
<form name = "actorInsert" align = "center" action="actorInserting.php" onSubmit="return ValidateActInsert()">
    Actor name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "actInsert"
    <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Insert">
</form>
```

I suggest using https://regexr.com/ to test expressions and to learn from some examples.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! As a side question, what could I do so that it catches things like "6z" as well as an invalid input?

Comment: `/([6z])\w+/g` I suggest using https://regexr.com/ to test regexp values. Also, depends on what would classify an invalid input.

Comment: For this particular field, only letters are allowed, so if I type in just numbers, it restricts it, but when I type in both a letter and a number then it still goes through when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Kappa123 I gave you an example for letters and numbers, and letters only.

Comment: @Kappa123 let me know if any other issues.

Comment: Actually yeah just a quick question, I've got a block of code of the same format as above for each of the fields in the forms. One of my forms has ~5 fields within it. Is it possible to somehow shorten it down so that I don't have to 4 separate blocks for each field?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex.test(val)

**^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$**

> ^ start
>
> [0-9a-zA-Z] only allow the characters inside [ ]
>
> $ end         * as many characters as it contains

```js
function ValidateActInsert() {
  var regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/;
  var val = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  if(!regex.test(val)){
    alert("false");
  }else{
    alert("true");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name = "actorInsert" align = "center" action="actorInserting.php" onSubmit="return ValidateActInsert()">
    Actor name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "actInsert">
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Insert">
</form>
```